# Subfloor hole/rot and stains - Is my approach correct?

Tags: subfloor, rot

Planned to replace carpet with wood and pulling up carpet revealed areas with water/pee stains and rotting/crumbly plywood subfloor. A couple of areas that were rotting had black dust but it does not look like mold (hopefully not) and are right inside the door.

For water/pee stains, I plan to use Zinsser BIN to seal it all in

For rotting/missing part of subfloor, I plan to put in a backer rod in some areas and thinset mortar in others.

Is my approach good?
[image]
Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhXOx.jpg)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rotting/missing subfloor == rip out the remains (cut back to undamaged area of floor) and replace with new subfloor, **not** fill with backer rod and/or thinset, neither of which are remotely equivalent to subfloor.

If it's particleboard (appears to be) that also applies to water-damaged areas. You say plywood but it does not appear to be plywood in your pictures.

Comment: I suppose that if Frank enjoys this kind of work, some filler would be fine because he'd likely be doing it again in a year or two.

Comment: Thanks! Subfloor turned out to be OSB structural panels by Weyerhaueser. It was probably unpainted and exposed to water/weather from a leaky door area. Does the advice to replace the panel still apply?

Comment: Depends on its condition post-water-exposure. Some OSB is more weather-resistant than other OSB, so that can vary. If it shows signs of swelling or delamination, cut back to where it does not. If it appears not to have swelled or delaminated, you might well be OK.